# Line up text elements horizontally and vertically after colon using divs

Tags: css

Given that I have items in CSS that look like this:

```
Event Starts: 26 October 2013

Event Ends: 28 October 2013

Location: The Neigh Court Yard, London, E19 4AF
```

How would I line them up vertically/horizontally in CSS so it looks like this:

```
Event Starts:   26 October 2013

Event Ends:     28 October 2013

Location:       The Neigh Court Yard, London, E19 4AF
```

Code so far:

```
        <div class="fb">
        Event Starts: 26 October 2013<br>
        Event Ends: 28 October 2013<br>
        Location: The Neigh Court Yard, London, E19 4AFF<br>
        Please note that this event has already taken place.
        </div>
```

Comment: Have tried using table?

Comment: @Cherry - I know it can be done that way but would prefer not to, and learn how to use divs

Comment: I know using tables is not a good way to do that, you can try using css frame work like bootstrap . Which can make your life easier in aligning the text and designing.

Comment: Are you able to change the markup inside the <div class="fb"> div?

Comment: Are you able to change the markup inside the <div class="fb"> div? - @ScottS yes I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a JSFiddle showing](http://jsfiddle.net/fhhrcdfL/4/) one way to do it. Wrapping each line in a `div`, each part of the line inside of a `p` and setting `width` and `float` of each.

html:

```
<div class="formBlock">
    <div class="info"><p>Event Starts:</p> <p>26 October 2013</p></div>
    <div class="info"><p>Event Ends:</p> <p> 28 October 2013</p></div>
    <div class="info"><p>Location:</p> <p> The Neigh Court Yard, London, E19 4AFF</p></div>
    <p class="last">Please note that this event has already taken place.</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.formBlock {
    width: 100%;
}

.info {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
p{
    float: left;
}
p:nth-of-type(even){
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 80%;
}

p:nth-of-type(odd){
    width: 20%;
}

p.last {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ghmtzrr5/

```
<table class="fb">
    <tr>
        <td class="firstCell">
        Event Starts:
        </td>
        <td>
             26 October 2013
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td class="firstCell">
        Event Ends: 
        </td>
        <td>
            28 October 2013
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="firstCell">
        Location: 
        </td>
        <td>
            The Neigh Court Yard, London, E19 4AFF
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        Please note that this event has already taken place.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

table td
{
border: 1px solid black;
}

.firstCell
{
width: 100px;
}
```

//UPDATE, without table

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ghmtzrr5/1/

Comment: Is it possible just using divs?

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/eLv5j7fs/

```
<div class="fb">
    <span>Event Starts:</span> 26 October 2013<br>
    <span>Event Ends:</span> 28 October 2013<br>
    <span>Location:</span> The Neigh Court Yard, London, E19 4AFF<br>
    Please note that this event has already taken place.
</div>
```

styling the span like this:

```
span {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a wrapper to split these 2 elements.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
        <p>Event Starts</p>
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>: 26 October 2013</p>
        ....
    </div>
</div>

.wrap{
width:80%; /*what ever size you wish*/
```

}

```
.left,
.right{
    width:50%;
    text-align:left;
}
left{
    float:left;
}
right{
    float:right;
}

//if you choose this method you can best scale left and right down to 49.5%
//this way you keep everything as responsive as can be. 
.mid{
    width:1%;
}

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="right">
        <p>Event Starts</p>
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="mid">
        <p>:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <p> 26 October 2013</p>
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```